# Fragment not replaced when using replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have created an activity which is containing 2 fragments.
Both fragment are displayed in the same layout of the activity.

Activity layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The first fragment is loaded at first and it works well.

I am loading the first fragment in the `main_container` using this command

```
    replaceFragment(ForgotPasswordEmailFragment(), R.id.main_container)
```

the `ForgotPasswordEmailFragment` contain a button and when I click on it, it suppose to load another fragment by replacing this one by the new one using the code below:

```
val forgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment: Fragment = ForgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.forgot_password_email_fragment, forgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

When the `ForgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment` is loaded, I am loading the new layout using the code below:

```
fragmentForgotPasswordNewPasswordBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_forgot_password_new_password, container, false)
        return fragmentForgotPasswordNewPasswordBinding.root
```

What happened is that the layout of `ForgotPasswordEmailFragment` is still there and the layout from `ForgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment` is also displayed. the fragment is not replaced at all

Any idea why?

Comment: You're using `R.id.main_container` for one `replace` and `R.id.forgot_password_email_fragment` for the other. Those aren't the same container. Did you mean them to be completely separate containers?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same container id while replacing any fragment. i.e `main_container`

```
val forgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment: Fragment = ForgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, forgotPasswordNewPasswordFragment)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
```